# math operation (plus/minus) in js

Tags: javascript, math

I have a simple function, that should generate 1000 different elements:

```
var start = 0,
step = 0.0001

for (var i=0; i<1000; i++){
  console.log(start);
  start -= i*step;
  console.log(start);
}
```

The trouble is that I'm getting not precisely what I've expected:

[image]

**How do I get price numbers in that case?** Actually I need 
0
-0.0001
-0.0002
-0.0003
...

should I round those numbers all the time or there is simplier solution?

Comment: In short: floating points (JavaScript numbers) are not very precise. Use them with caution.

Comment: You can use number.toFixed(4) to get precise answers.```start = start.toFixed(4);``` after your subtraction should do it

Comment: it's javascript, you should handle decimals in server side

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are not precise! However, you're not helping the situation, because you're compounding the imprecision. Instead of repeatedly subtracting from start, why don't you compute each value individually.

**edit**: *incorrect code removed*

The numbers aren't going to be perfect but at least this mitigates the problem of floating point precision, as each value doesn't depend on the last.

Comment: Which gives a totally different result than what the OP is doing... `start -= i*step;` !==  `out = -i * step;`

Comment: it's not the case for me. in whole i have noumerous stock quotes on the page and when user selects one of them, I need to substract minimum step from that quote and get "next best" quote

as if var Q = 500.25 var min_step = 0.01 and I need to get 500.24

Comment: My code is completely incorrect, please ignore it. If the answers to the other question don't help you, you should edit this one.